# Gradle multi project and quarkus giving a "Expected main resources to contain exactly one file, however, it contains more than one file"

Tags: gradle, quarkus

I'm trying to get quarkus working with a server stub from swagger-code-gen - if I comment out the server stub, things work fine - but as soon as i add the dependency, it breaks.

The error I get is: "Expected main resources to contain exactly one file, however, it contains more than one file."

Here are my three gradle files:

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    plugins {
        id "${quarkusPluginId}" version "${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }
}

rootProject.name = 'mini-service'
include 'endpoints'
include 'app'
```

(endpoints) build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' version '2.18.2'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    swaggerCodegen 'io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-cli:3.0.23'
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compileOnly 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    compileOnly 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:3.0.11.Final'
    compile 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.0.9'
}

swaggerSources {
    petstore {
        inputFile = file('petstore.yaml')
        code {
            language = 'jaxrs-resteasy'
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn swaggerSources.petstore.code
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "${swaggerSources.petstore.code.outputDir}/src/gen/java"
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "${swaggerSources.petstore.code.outputDir}/src/gen/resources"

group 'uk.co.landbay'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

And finally the quarkus app build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.3.72"
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-amqp'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-json'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'

    implementation project(':endpoints')

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}


group 'uk.co.landbay'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.ws.rs.Path")
    annotation("javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped")
    annotation("io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    kotlinOptions.javaParameters = true
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

No doubt there are plenty of dependency issues to work through at some point - but right now i'm just trying to get the quarkus app to build - I get the following error **"Expected main resources to contain exactly one file, however, it contains more than one file."** but not sure where the 'multiple' resources files come from.

Other notes:

1. commenting out the dependency (implementation project(':endpoints')) does not help.
2. Removing the subproject does help - e.g. if gradle doesn't know about the other submodule, quarkus builds fine.
3. The JAR file from
   :endpoints does build fine - but not sure if it is relevant as
4. removing the dependency doesn't help the build

This is the stack strace i get:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected main resources to contain exactly one file, however, it contains more than one file.
> at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:105)
> at io.quarkus.gradle.builder.QuarkusModelBuilder.getSourceSourceSet(QuarkusModelBuilder.java:418)
> at io.quarkus.gradle.builder.QuarkusModelBuilder.getWorkspaceModule(QuarkusModelBuilder.java:211)

Comment: Did you end up solving this?